# How to reorder ListView with custom cursor adapter when no scrolling is involved?

Tags: java, android

I have `'profiles'` activity that shows a `ListView` items and from there the user picks 1-5 items (max 5) and goes in another `'showcase'` activity which shows these items. I'm using the cursor adapter to display the listview in both activities but obviously it displays only the chosen 5 in the `'showcase'` activity and here I want to reorder them. I really don't care how will the ordering work... looking for the simplest solution out there. I don't think RecyclerView is a good idea because all the items will be visible all the time and there won't be any scrolling. Any approach will be helpful.. but at least something because i'm really stuck..! I'm having a database associated with the `ListView` and maybe I can put a field for order number or something..??